# Setblock for conditional command block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

does anyone know how I would use the setblock command to set a conditional command block? I know that there is a NBT tag for it, I just dont know how to implement that into my current command. Appreciate all help!

My current command is
*

> /setblock ~ ~-1 ~-3 chain_command_block 3 replace {Command:/testfor
>   @p[score_Money_min=110]}

*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no tag for it. It's instead saved as the Damage value. See [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Command_Block#Block_data) for a list of values.

For your command, you'd add 8 to the Damage value, resulting in 11:

```
/setblock ~ ~-1 ~-3 minecraft:chain_command_block 11 replace {Command:"/testfor @p[score_Money_min=110]"}
```

Comment: That's what I meant, a damage value. Thanks for the help!